# AngularJs : appending select box dynamically

Tags: angularjs, append

I need to add select box dynamically. For that i used following code.

```
  $scope.newsource = ["New South Wales","Victoria"];
  angular.element(document.getElementById('testdiv')).append($compile("<select ng-model='selectedVal' ng-options='key for key in "+$scope.newsource+"' ng-change='dropdownChanged(selectedVal)'><option value=''>--select--</option></select>")($scope));
```

However options are not getting listed. How can i make it work?

Code:

```
    myApp.directive("cascadingDropdowns", [
      "$compile", function($compile) {
        return {
          restrict: "E",
          replace: true,
          scope: {
            noOfDropdowns: '=',
            source: '='
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attr) {

         },
          templateUrl: "../templates/cascading-dropdown/cascading-dropdown.html",
          controller: function($scope, $compile, $http) {
            $scope.dropdownChanged = function(selectedVal) {
              if(selectedVal != null)
              {
                $scope.newsource = ["New South Wales","Victoria"];
                angular.element(document.getElementById('testdiv')).append($compile("<select ng-model='selectedVal' ng-options='key for key in $scope.newsource' ng-change='dropdownChanged(selectedVal)'><option value=''>--select--</option></select>")($scope));
              }
            };
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
```

cascading-dropdown.html ;

```
  <div id="testdiv"><select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="key for (key, value) in source" ng-change="dropdownChanged(selectedVal)">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
  </select></div>
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Is that inside in a directive? It would help to have that code as well

Comment: yes it is inside directive. I think there is something wrong with ng-options='key for key in "+$scope.newsource+"'

Comment: can u post the full code u have tried ?

Comment: post the code for controller and the usage of the `cascadingDropdowns` directive in html ?

Comment: Did you try: `ng-options='key for key in newsource'`?

Comment: @jcubic yes.. but no luck